# How to clear textbox in WPF MVVM with clear button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Okay, so I wanna clear the text in my textbox with a click from a button. Both are placed within the first stackpanel in the XAML code. I'm trying to make it work with commands and bindings, but I just can't seem to make it work.. Any suggestions? SqlQueryCommand is bound to the clear button, SqlQueryString is bound to the textbox.

Vievmodel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WpfMVVM.Commands;

namespace PoC.ViewModels
{
    class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand ClearSqlQueryCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand ClearFilterCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand ClearFilterByIdCommand { get; private set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string sqlQueryString;
    private string filterString;
    private string filterByIdString;
    public string SqlQueryString
    {
        get
        {
            return sqlQueryString;
        }
        set
        {
            sqlQueryString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SqlQueryString));
        }
    }

    public string FilterString
    {
        get
        {
            return filterString;
        }
        set
        {
            filterString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilterString));
        }
    }

    public string FilterByIdString
    {
        get
        {
            return filterByIdString;
        }
        set
        {
            filterByIdString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilterByIdString));
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ClearSqlQueryCommand = new RelayCommand(ClearSqlQuery, CanClearSqlQuery);
        ClearFilterCommand = new RelayCommand(ClearFilter, CanClearFilter);
        ClearFilterByIdCommand = new RelayCommand(ClearFilterById, CanClearFilterById);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public void ClearSqlQuery(object parameter)
    {
        SqlQueryString = string.Empty;
    }

    public bool CanClearSqlQuery(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ClearFilter(object parameter)
    {

    }

    public bool CanClearFilter(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ClearFilterById(object parameter)
    {

    }

    public bool CanClearFilterById(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

RelayCommand:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfMVVM.Commands
{
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
   {
    Action<object> _execute;
    Func<object, bool> _canExecute;


    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute != null)
        {
            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="PoC.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PoC"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:PoC.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TreeView>
    </TreeView>
    
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SqlQueryString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="30" Width="450" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button Content="Execute" Margin="10 0" Padding="5 0"/>
            <Button Content="Clear" Padding="5 0" Command="{Binding ClearSqlQueryCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FilterString}" Grid.Row="0" Height="30" Width="200"/>
            <Button Content="Filter" Margin="10 0" Padding="5 0"/>
            <Button Content="Clear" Padding="5 0" Margin="0 0 115 0"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FilterByIdString}" Grid.Row="0" Height="30" Width="100"/>
            <Button Content="Filter" Margin="10 0 0 0" Padding="5 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderThickness="0 1 1 1"/>
    </Grid>
    
    
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ye, the setter is hit, and the value is "".

Comment: For the future, note that it is easier to answer your question if you trim down the problem by removing irrelevant parts of the code / XAML.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing `: INotifyPropertyChanged`on the `MainWindowViewModel`class.

Answer (score -2):

You can easily do that by setting its value to "".

`texbox.Text="";`

Comment: Well ye, but that's not using bindings and commands

Comment: You have suggested the code behind approach, which violates MVVM as it does not use a command for the button or binding for the textbox text. You're using the reference name of the textbox control.

Comment: @MuhammadAli code-behind and using references to controls does not violate MVVM. Commands and data binding are not defined in MVVM. MVVM is a design pattern. By definition it must be language/compiler and platform/framework independent. It only shows a Osten on how to design your application so that your business logic is not coupled to the UI. Code-behind and data binding are language features of the C# compiler. Code-behind is a very important feature, because XAML is only a markup language with limited power. For example,  we depend on code-behind for more complex logic or event handling.

Comment: @MuhammadAli If you stick to your misunderstanding, you will very likely write code that really violates MVVM because UI logic is implemented in the View Model which according to MVVM belongs to the View - just to avoid code-behind. MVVM is about responsibilities and not technology or language features. It's an architectural design pattern.